# Modelling a mutable collection in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Our existing application loads approximately ten million rows from a database into a collection of objects on startup. The collection is stored in a GigaSpaces cache.

As new messages are received by the application, the cache is checked to see if an entry for that message already exists. If not, a new entity is added to the cache based on the data in the message. (At the same time, the new entity is persisted to a database).

We are investigating the feasibility and value add of re-architecting the application using Spark and Scala. The question is, what would be the correct way to model this in Spark.

My first thought is to load from the database into a Spark RDD. Looking up existing entries would obviously be simple. However, because an RDD is immutable, adding new entries to the cache would require a transformation. Given the large set of data, my presumption is that this would not perform well.

The other idea is to create the cache as a mutable Scala collection. However, how would we then integrate this with Spark, given that Spark works with RDD's?

Thanks

Comment: "My first thought is to load from the database into a Spark RDD. Looking up existing entries would obviously be simple". Er, no, it wouldn't, What operation were you thinking of using to look up whether an entry exists? It might need to look on every node... To me, Spark and RDDs seem a very bad fit for your use-case - SPark is about specifying how the data in a large dataset will be turned into an RDD, then defining a set of transformations on that RDD with the aim of producing some (possibly still quite large) result set. It's not a magic bullet for all use-cases for a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a design questions. Spark is not great for fast lookups. It is optimize for batch jobs that need to touch almost the entire dataset; potentially multiple times.

If you want something that has fast **search**-like capabilities you should look into [Elastic Search](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch).

Other technologies that are often used for storing large **in-memory/lookup** tables is [redis](http://redis.io) and [memcached](http://memcached.org).

Answer (score 1):

Since RDDs are immutable, every single cache update would require producing an entirely new RDD from your previous RDD. This is clearly inefficient (you have to manipulate the entire RDD just to update a tiny part of it). As for the other idea of having a mutable scala collection of RDD elements -- well, that won't be distributable across machines/CPUs, so what's the point?

If your goal is to have in-memory, distributable/partitionable operations on your cache, what you're looking for is an operational in-memory data grid, not Apache Spark. For example: Hazelcast, ScaleOut software, etc.

Apache Spark is notoriously bad at fine-grained transformations like the ones you would need for an in-memory distributed cache.

Sorry if I'm not directly answering the technical question, instead I'm answering your question behind your question...